# ContentControl - Content setter inside ItemsControl

Tags: xaml, setter, contentcontrol

I have a weird Behaviour in my ContentControl and don't see why it behaves this way.

This Xaml code list the items of my ObservableCollection

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Stops}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>

                <local:TripDetailListItemControl />

            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But this only displays the First item of the List

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Stops}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>

                                <local:TripDetailListItemControl/>

                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What is the Difference? Am I missing an Enumarator with the Style override?

The Background, why I need it this way, is that I have a Proeprty in this `TripDetailListItemControl` that changes the view of this Item. So I want a DataTrigger in this Style to Display it a different way.

But the list is not shown in the first place. What to I need to add in the Content Setter to display all Items?

Comment: “Missing an enumerator with the style override” doesn’t mean anything so that’s probably not the issue. Try writing a [DataTemplateSelector for the ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) to swap in different itemtemplates. That’s the correct way to do it. Also make sure your collection is populated. Don’t make assumptions about what’s wrong. Check every possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add BasedOn:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
```

or:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
     <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <local:TripDetailListItemControl/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```